# How to check all text boxes are empty before clicking calculate

Tags: javascript

Hi all im new to jscipt,,, well, programming in general to be honest, but learning slowly for personal use.
I seek guidence on how i could place all the textboxes(inputs) in my index file into a list container, loop through them to check if they are empty or not before clicking the calculate button. If they are empty then inform the user of which one is empty.
Also, is there a way of preventing users from entering text into the textboxes and numbers only.
Background: im creating a form that requires all fields to be populate with numbers(in hours),  a graph will then be generated from those values.
ive placed the file in skydrive for folks to download with the link below.

[Index file](http://sdrv.ms/Vj56Et)

I did try the following but this alerts me regardless of weather the texboxes are populate or not.

```
function checkInputsGenerateGraph()
{
if( $('#hutz-hoursInput').val() == ""||$('#hutz-weeksPerYearInput').val() ==      ""||$('#hutz-jobsPerWeekInput').val() == ""||$('#hutz-hourlyMachineRateInput').val() == ""||$('#hutz-maintneneceDowntimeInput').val() == ""||$('#hutz-scrapRateInput').val() == ""||$('#hutz-toolsPerJobInput').val() == ""||$('#hutz-timeToLoadToolInput').val() == ""||$('#hutz-timeToSetPartsInput').val() == "")
{
alert('One them is empty!!');
}
else
{
$("#hutz-graph").slideDown();  
                    $("#hutz-lblImproveMyProcess").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-hoursInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-weeksPerYearInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-jobsPerWeekInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-ourlyMachineRateInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-ntneneceDowntimeInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-scrapRateInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-toolsPerJobInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-timeToLoadToolInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-timeToSetPartsInput").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-lblMachineDetails").slideUp();
                    $("#hutz-lblPartSetting").slideUp();
                       $("#hutzcurrencyPreferenceInput").slideUp();
                    createChart();                      
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, give all the required elements a common class, for examples sake we'll call this `required`:

```
<input type="text" class="required" id="hutz-hoursInput" />
```

Then, when your `checkInputsGenerateGraph()` function is called, you can loop over the `required` elements and check them:

```
$('.required').each(function() {
  if (this.value.length == 0) {
    alert(this.id + ' is empty!');
  } 
});
```

You could also do something like the following to remove all non-digits from your inputs:

```
$('.required').change(function() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^\d]+/, '');
});
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/GkF4h/9/)**

Hope that points you in the right direction!

**edit**

Here's a complete example:-

```
function checkInputsGenerateGraph() {

  var isValid = true;

  $('.example').each(function() {
    if (this.value.length == 0) {
      alert(this.id + ' is empty!');
      isValid = false; 
    } 
  });

  if (isValid) {
    alert('do calculations!');   
  }
}
```

So, loop over all of the elements first, and make sure they are all populated. If not, set `isValid` to false so that once the loop completes, the calculations are not performed.

Comment: Many thanks for that billy, i did this but included an else(not else if) in the if statement to say if they are populated then slide everything and show the graph, however, if one of the textboxes are empty the alert will show which is great, but the graph will still show.  Am i missing something?

Comment: @user1996641 check out the [fiddle I posted](http://jsfiddle.net/GkF4h/9/), you need to run your calculate functions after the loop has completed, otherwise it will trigger everytime a value isn't empty :)

Comment: I cant seem to find anywhere on the web how to set the form width and height, can you help ? i need it to be fixed at 1024x768